# Сборка PHP файлов

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Есть некий небольшой проект, который целиком располагается в одной папке.
Как собрать все файлы в папке в один php-файл? Как это сделано в проекте Adminer.
Может утилита какая-то используется?

Comment: название сей дивной утилиты - руки

Answer (score 1):

[Phar](http://php.net/phar)

> The phar extension provides a way to
> put entire PHP applications into a
> single file called a "phar" (PHP
> Archive) for easy distribution and
> installation. In addition to providing
> this service, the phar extension also
> provides a file-format abstraction
> method for creating and manipulating
> tar and zip files through the PharData
> class, much as PDO provides a unified
> interface for accessing different
> databases. Unlike PDO, which cannot
> convert between different databases,
> Phar also can convert between tar, zip
> and phar file formats with a single
> line of code. see
> Phar::convertToExecutable() for one
> example.
>
> What is phar? Phar archives are best
> characterized as a convenient way to
> group several files into a single
> file. As such, a phar archive provides
> a way to distribute a complete PHP
> application in a single file and run
> it from that file without the need to
> extract it to disk. Additionally, phar
> archives can be executed by PHP as
> easily as any other file, both on the
> commandline and from a web server.
> Phar is kind of like a thumb drive for
> PHP applications.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
for i in /home/zzzz/src/*
do
    cat $i >> bigfile.php
done
```